# How to see all the frameworks cocoapods links to

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

for instance im using the 'AmazonAd' pod and here(https://developer.amazon.com/docs/mobile-ads/mb-ios-quick-start-guide.html) it shows i need to add these frameworks, I know cocoapods does this for me but is there a way I can see in my actual xcode project where they are listed the frameworks cocoapods is linking for me ?
Add the following frameworks if they are not already linked AdSupport.framework,CoreLocation.framework,SystemConfiguration.framework"
etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the frameworks in the [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/c/f/4/AmazonAd/2.2.15.1/AmazonAd.podspec.json#L21):

```
  "frameworks": [
    "AdSupport",
    "CoreLocation",
    "SystemConfiguration",
    "CoreTelephony",
    "MediaPlayer",
    "EventKit",
    "EventKitUI",
    "StoreKit",
    "QuartzCore",
    "SafariServices",
    "JavaScriptCore"
  ],
```

Comment: so cocoapods hides this in the xcode project and it is only visible in the podspec ?, I was looking where we would normally add frameworks in the buildsettings and dont see the added frameworks only "libpods-myapp.a"

Comment: After a `pod install` or `pod update`, you can also see the frameworks in the `Link Binary with Libraries` Build Phase of the Build Target for the pod which is one of the targets added for the `Pods` project in the generated Xcode workspace.

Comment: do you know what the 'platform' should be set to in the pod file ? by default its ios 9.0 is this suppose to be deployment target or minimum ios required ?

Comment: Set `platform` to the minimum ios level that you want to support with your app. Note that it must be greater or equal to the maximum level of the pods the app depends on.

Comment: Sorry im kind of confused by this statement what do you mean by "it must be greater or equal to the maximum level of the pods the app depends on"  to clarify my app's deployment target is 8.0 and all the pods support 8.0 and up , so your saying set it to the minimum my app supports (8.0) but then saying it must be greater or equal to the max level of the pods the app depends on (the pod supports higher than 8.0) also what happens if i just do 'platform : ios' ?with no number